# Smart Array P420i, Logical Drive failed, best way to re-enable

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array, raid10

I have a HP Proliant ML380p Gen8 server with a P420i controller where one of the logical drives suddenly failed.

[Screenshot Smart Storage Administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY7KY.jpg)

From what I could see in the Smart Storage Administrator, none of the physical drives in the array seems to have a problem. It gives me the option to re-enable the failed logical drive (see screenshot), but I have understood from various forum posts that if this doesn't work I will loose all data on the disks. Therefore, I decided to first create copies of all four drives. I used ddrescue and a USB SATA dock to create those copies, and I managed to get a full copy of drives B and D (see screenshot). From both drive A and drive C however I could only copy about 74% of the disk before ddrescue was unable to read more data.

In a raid 1+0 array, the disks are supposed to have a layout like this:

[Raid 1+0 layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c99rF.png)

So I now have the following questions:

- If the drives A,B,C,D are configured in the order as shown in the screenshot of the Smart Storage Administrator above, does this mean that (A + B) is a Raid 1 pair, and that (C + D) is also a raid 1 pair, and that by having full copies of drive B and D, I have a copy of all data?

If the above is true, then I'm looking for advice on how to try to 're-enable the logical drive':

- Should I put all 4 drives back in the server, including the ones that I couldn't fully read using ddrescue, and then try to re-enable OR
- Should I only put drives B and D back in the server (the ones that I could fully read using ddrescue) and then try to re-enable?

Thanks in advance for answers to these questions, or any other tips or advice

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your server is more than two years past it's end of support date - which isn't ideal. Also I'd not even bother with this idea to 'create copies of all four drives' - that's highly unlikely to get you anywhere.

If you still have access to your data then simply back it up if you haven't already - destroy and recreate the logical disk and restore your data. I know it's a lot of work and required downtime but it's the only way to know for sure that you'll end up with a working system.

Or...get a supported newer server and restore to that - fixes two problems!

Answer (score 1):

Just reenable the logical drive. 
I'd ask what the precipitating event was, but it's probably not important.

Answer (score 1):

> I could only copy about 74% of the disk before ddrescue was unable to read more data.

You seem to have fallen for the *RAID protects my data in any case* myth. RAID is only as good as your checking and monitoring - bit rot can lead to multiple read failures when not checked on a regular basis; multiple read failures lead to your array failing altogether. Also, RAID does not replace a current, good and tested backup.

1. Test the drives thoroughly (or replace outright).
2. Replace any faulty/untrustworthy drives.
3. Re-enable the array, formatting the drives.
4. Restore from backup.
5. Make sure you enable weekly/regular data scrubbing aka media patrol to avoid future stale read errors.